# Does pytest support multiprocessing.set_start_method?

Tags: python, pytest, python-multiprocessing

The doc of `multiprocessing.set_start_method` note that:

> Note that this should be called at most once, and it should be protected inside the if **name** == '**main**' clause of the main module.

However, if I put `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` in a pytest module fixture, I do not know will does it work perfectly.

Comment: Why don't you try it and report the results? 

Pytest will execute the fixture at the start of the module. 

If multiprocessing doesn't play nicely with pytest fixture, you can simply create a regular python helper function instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you really do always want to use the same start method, you can set it in a session-scoped fixture in the file `conftest.py` in the root of your source tree. E.g.

```py
# conftest.py
import multiprocessing
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def always_spawn():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
```

Comment: this seems to work only for running a single test. When I try to fix the start method to "fork" and run pytest in my root directory, all of my tests are throwing an exception:
`RuntimeError: context has already been set`

Comment: Adding "force = True" to the `set_start_method` arguments fixes this (I guess `pytest` sometimes sets the start method before the fixture is called)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as stated in the documentation, you will be in trouble if you try to call [`multiprocessing.set_start_method()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) from multiple unit tests functions. Moreover, this will affect your whole program and may interoperate badly with the entire tests suit.

However, there exists a workaround which is described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) too:

> Alternatively, you can use [`get_context()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_context) to obtain a context
>   object. Context objects have the same API as the multiprocessing
>   module, and allow one to use multiple start methods in the same
>   program.
>
> ````py
> import multiprocessing as mp
>
> def foo(q):
>     q.put('hello')
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
>     q = ctx.Queue()
>     p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
>     p.start()
>     print(q.get())
>     p.join() ```
> ````

This method can be used per-test to avoid compatibility issues discussed. It can be combined with "monkeypatching" or "mocking" to test your class with different start methods:

```py
# my_class.py

import multiprocessing

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def process(self, x):
        # Very simplified example of a method using a multiprocessing Queue 
        self._queue.put(x)
        return self._queue.get()
```

```py
# tests/test_my_class.py

import multiprocessing
import my_class

def test_spawn(monkeypatch):
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
    monkeypatch.setattr(my_class.multiprocessing, "Queue", ctx.Queue)
    obj = my_class.MyClass()
    assert obj.process(6) == 6

def test_fork(monkeypatch):
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')
    monkeypatch.setattr(my_class.multiprocessing, "Queue", ctx.Queue)
    obj = my_class.MyClass()
    assert obj.process(6) == 6
```

Comment: But if you do want to always use the same start method everywhere, using contexts are overkill.